# Git Submodule is not shown as changed after merging branch where it was updated

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitkraken

### Original Question

I am working in a git repository containing multiple submodules, one of which shows strange behaviour: I'm working on a feature branch, let's call it `featureBranch`. This branch was created from my `develop` branch. While I worked on my feature, someone updated the submodule and committed the changes to `develop`. My repository now looks like this:

```
* 10000003 (HEAD -> featureBranch) Work on my feature
| * 10000002 (develop) Update submodule
|/
* 10000001 some commit
```

To be up to date, I want to merge the current `develop` into `featureBranch` via `git merge develop`. Upon running a `git status` call, I would expect to see changes in the submodule, since my submodule is, of course, not yet updated to `develop`s' status. This, however, is not the case. After the merge, there are no submodule changes shown and the submodule remains in the state from commits `10000003` and `10000001`.

This is a simplified description of my repository and the number of commits. I tried to reproduce this with a minimal example repo, but was not able to. In a minimal case, everything works as expected, with the submodule showing changes after the merge and a `git submodule update` call setting it to its' stage from commit `10000002`. I can, however, repoduce this in my productive repository via `reset --hard` and a new `merge develop` as often as I want.

Aside the command line, I occasionaly use GitKraken, that has some known issues with submodules. I thus cannot exclude it as the source of this, but since this happens also when exclusively using the command line, it does not seem likely to me.

Does anyone have a clue why a submodule change from a branch where it was changed would not carry over on a merge to a branch where the submodule did not change? Any hints are appreciated.

### Remarks

As it turned out, the simplification in my question was not valid. In reality, `featureBranch` originated from `develop` a long time back. There where merges from `develop`to `featureBranch` from time to time, and I sucpect some of these merges along with local `develop` diverging from origins' and some hard resets in between as the source of this. Due to the tangled history, it's very hard to pinpoint the real reason, and I don't have time to untangle it all.

After merging `develop` into `featureBranch` and adding another commit changing the commit of the submodule in question, I looked at the submodule via GitKrakens' file history, and strangely it shows the following (read bottom-up):

```
+Commit 183 //new commit id
-Commit ad7 //commit id from develop the submodule should have been on after merge,
              but it actually was on ccc and did not show any changes!

**This is where the merge happened. Below is the file history from featureBranch

+Commit ccc //new commit id
-Commit ff9 //old commit id

+Commit ff9 //new commit id
-Commit bb6 //old commit id

+Commit bb6 //new commit id
-Commit 3f9 //old submodule commit id
```

I am still very confused about this issue, but will not investigate futher. If anyone can bring light to this, I would be very happy.

Comment: what do you mean about `ccc`?

Comment: In the previous commit, the target commit in the submodule was set from `ff9` to `ccc`. When I changed it again, I expected it to change from `ccc` to the new commit `183`, instead it changed from `ad7` to the new `183`, all triplets here being commit hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You must think submodules as a parallel repositories first.

Your main repository (who contains the submodules) just aim to commits in the submodule history. For example: When you merge the **develop** into your **featureBranch** the commit hashes of the submodules in **develop** will now be the same in the **featureBranch** BUT you must update them manually (and that's why you should avoid GUIs).

After merge run `git submodule update` and you will have all the updates (if has) from the submodules. Also if you are using submodules in a specific branch and want to update them to the last commit run `git submodule update --remote`.

Here you can have a good overview how submodules work: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm well aware that changes in submodules only change the target commit inside the submodule, and if the merge would work as expected I would have to update the submodules manually. But running `git submodule update` yields no results. The parent repository still thinks the submodule should be at the commit of `featureBranch`, and not the newly defined one from `develop`.

Comment: Then happened one of these scenarios: 1) The merge assumed the current commits in the featureBranch and that's why you don't get the new ones. 2) The commits in develop are older then the ones in featureBranch then git didn't change them. 3) The commits in develop doesnt exists in the repository, for example, the developer changed something in the submodule, committed but didnt push the change in the submodule then the develop aim to commit hashes that doesnt exist yet in the remote.

Comment: 2) The commits touching the submodule on `develop` are newer than those on `featureBranch`, although I think git does not care about time, but just compares branch `HEAD`s and merge base. 3) The submodule commits do exist and are pushed to remote. When I check out `develop` and run `submodule update` it works fine. 
Considering 1), I realized that this issue might be more complex than I initally assumed. I will do some research and modify the question accordingly (or delete it and start a new one). Thanks for your help so far.